# Create Silverlight controls dynamically for each ItemsControl item

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, .net-4.0

I want to bind list of objects each of it has UIType (ie textbox, checkbox, combo etc). And it has object Value property.

I want to bind this list to an ItemControl (ListBox, DataGrid..) where each item will have separate template corresponding to the particular UIType of each object (eg item for combo will have combo in the row and item for checkbox will have checkbox)...

obviously prop Value will be bound to relevant property on each item.

whats the most transparent and not too elaborate way to achieve this?

Silverlight 5.

**EDIT: (working code based on the Jacob's solution)**

code:

```
ObservableCollection<UIType> data;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    data = new ObservableCollection<UIType>() 
    { 
        new UITypeTextBox() { Value = "Value.." }, 
        new UITypeCheckBox(){ Value = true },  
    };

    lb.ItemsSource = data;
}

public class UIType { }
public class UITypeTextBox  : UIType { public object Value { get; set; }}
public class UITypeCheckBox : UIType { public object Value { get; set; } }
```

xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:UITypeTextBox">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:UITypeCheckBox">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about Silverlight but in WPF you can use data templates to do this.  For each of your UI types you define a data template which basically maps a type to a view which is just a user control defined i XAML.

Typically you will define the data templates in a resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
    xmlns:uitypes="clr-namespace:MyApp.UITypes"
    >

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type uitypes:TextBox}">
        <views:TextBoxView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type uitypes:CheckBox}">
        <views:CheckBoxView />
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Your views would be XAML files inheriting from UserControl.  For example the XAML for the TextBox view might look like the following.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.TextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />    
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

WPF (and hopefully Silverlight) automatically pics the right view when you add your UI types to an ItemControl.

Comment: Last I checked, Silverlight does not support implicit DataTemplates (data templates without an x:Key). The alternative is to use a `DataTemplateSelector` which returns a template based on the item type

Comment: I would really like to go without creating whole user control to cater just for one commong control like text box or combo... all this mvvm histeria is just too vague

Comment: @Rachel: Silverlight 5 does support implicit DataTemplates, see http://jesseliberty.com/2011/04/21/implicit-data-templates-silverlight-5/ .  Bobb has specified in his question that he's using SL5.

Comment: @Bobb You don't need to use a `UserControl` in your `DataTemplate`; you can simply write whatever control you want there instead. And Jakob thanks, I didn't realize SL5 had implicit DataTemplates finally :)

Comment: I know how data template look like. you answer lacks the key information - how do i set the template for each item individually?

Comment: @Bobb: You don't have to set the template for each item.  All you have to do is add your objects to your ItemControl and Silverlight will figure out which data template to use based on the DataType="{x:Type ...}" part.

Comment: @JakobChristensen thats completely new for me.. So I did small prototype and it doesnt work for me. Please have a look at the edit of the question - could you please tell whats wrong with it?

P.S. DataType doesnt take enum as a type - so I had to inherit objects from different classes

Comment: OK. You were right. I am changing the EDIT to the working version for other users... thanks